# Can't open BMP files for viewing from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, images, bmp

When double clicking `.bmp` image files in Windows Explorer or selecting in "Open With" either MS Paint or default image viewer or third party like Irfanview, they won't open.

Perhaps has to do with registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp` and change something there, i tried to fix, but end up deleting that key completely yet still cant open.

Comment: Are you sure these are valid `.bmp` files ? When displayed as text, such as by using notepad, they should start with the characters `BM`.

Comment: If you open *from* MS Paint using File menu, do these same files fail to open as well? As it is your question lacks every bit of research.